# R - Grouping of Data

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate

I have a Dataset in the following way:

```
 Incoming_Day  STU_ID
1 2016-04-27 A033548
2 2017-05-18 A034571
3 2017-01-27 A034623
4 2016-01-04 A100170
5 2016-01-05 A100170
```

I want to make a data frame where against each day, the number of students operating will be shown.

I have used the following code:

```
df <- aggregate(data.frame(count = df$STU_ID), list(Incoming_Day= df$Incoming_Day), length); df[1:5,]
```

However the result I get is the number of observation against each day. I am sure I am doing a simple mistake here. How can I rectify it?

Comment: please post expected output

Comment: @PoGibas: 
     Incoming_Day  No_Of_Students_Registration
    1 2016-04-27 3
    2 2017-05-18 5
    3 2017-01-27 9
    4 2016-01-04 6
    5 2016-01-05 5

and so on

Comment: @Raj. You can use `dput(df)` to extract a reproducible example from the original df loaded in the script. Or if you have a very large sample and wanted to grab the first 10 lines use `dput(head(x = df, n =10))`. Where the x argument is for the data object and n is for a number of lines to sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
aggregatedDF <- aggregate(data = df, STU_ID ~ Incoming_Day , 
                          function(x) length(unique(x)) )
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using function(x) followed by **length(unique(x))**, like this:

```
aggregate(data.frame(count=df$STU_ID),list(Incoming_Day=df$Incoming_Day),
          function(x) length(unique(x)))
```

Output:

```
  Incoming_Day count
1   2016-01-04     1
2   2016-01-05     2
3   2016-04-27     1
4   2017-01-27     1
5   2017-05-18     1
```

Sample data:

```
df <- fread("Incoming_Day  STU_ID
             2016-04-27 A033548
             2017-05-18 A034571
             2017-01-27 A034623
             2016-01-04 A100170
             2016-01-05 A100170
             2016-01-05 A100170
             2016-01-05 A100172")
```

Comment: why do you have to coerce variable subsets into a list and dataframe? You can accomplish your output without doing so.

Comment: @DataTx - That's a good question. It's true that the aggregate() syntax can be made simpler, as with your answer, depending on the desired output. The syntax I use has two main advantages though: (1) the output is a data frame; (2) the columns of said data frame can have custom names.

Comment: @RyanRunge: This was only the top 5 of the 80000 rows, and there are multiple STU_IDs. So I could cot use any manual input of the data values.

Comment: @Raj - No problem. This will work as a solution either way. I only added more sample data to demonstrate the output.